# How to use a list in a nested list that don't except list and wants string?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have this bit of code that works but I would like to use `ScoreList1` as a part of the nested list but is asking for a string not a list.

I need it to work with lists as I have an input that appends to a list.

```
ScoreList1= ['04', '05', '01', '07', '08']

nestedList = [["Judge","01","02","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple A","10","06","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple B","01","02","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple C","07","10","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple D","01","02","10","04","05"],]

for item in nestedList:
    print(
    ": "+item[0] + " "*(9-len(item[0]))+": "+
         item[1] + " "*(3-len(item[1]))+": "+
         item[4] + " "*(3-len(item[4]))+": "+
         item[2] + " "*(3-len(item[2]))+": "+
         item[3] + " "*(3-len(item[3]))+": "+
         item[5] + " "*(3-len(item[5]))+": ")
```

this is my expected output:

```
: Judge    : 01 : 04 : 02 : 03 : 05 : 
: Couple A : 10 : 04 : 06 : 03 : 05 : 
: Couple B : 01 : 04 : 02 : 03 : 05 : 
: Couple C : 07 : 04 : 10 : 03 : 05 : 
: Couple D : 01 : 04 : 02 : 10 : 05 :
```

but where the line couple a is I want the numbers in scorelist1

edited:

```
    ScoreList1= ['04', '05', '01', '07', '08']
ScoreList2= ['07', '02', '01', '02', '08']

nestedList = [["Judge","01","02","03","04","05"],
             ["Couple A","10","06","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple B","01","02","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple C","07","10","03","04","05"],
              ["Couple D","01","02","10","04","05"],]

for item in nestedList:
    row = item[:1] + ScoreList1 if item[0] == "Couple A" else item
    print(": {:<8} ".format(row[0])
          + "".join(": {:<2} ".format(field) for field in row[1:]))
```

need scorelist2 next to couple B

Edit 2:

```
    ScoreList1= ['04', '05', '01', '07', '08']
ScoreList2= ['07', '02', '01', '02', '08']
ScoreList3= ['02', '01', '01', '10', '08']
ScoreList4= ['01', '10', '02', '10', '09']
ScoreList5= ['02', '08', '01', '10', '01']
ScoreList6= ['01', '07', '01', '01', '01']

nestedListOfNames = [["Couple A"],
                     ["Couple B"],
                     ["Couple C"],
                     ["Couple D"],
                     ["Couple E"],
                     ["Couple F"]]
print(": Judge    : 01 : 02 : 03 : 04 : 05")
print("")
substitutions = {"Couple A": ScoreList1, "Couple B": ScoreList2, "Couple C": ScoreList3, "Couple D": ScoreList4, "Couple E" : ScoreList5, "Couple F" : ScoreList6}
with open("myfile.txt",'w') as outfile:
    for item in nestedListOfNames:
        row = item[:1] + substitutions.get(item[0], item[1:],)
        outfile.write(": {:<8} ".format(row[0])
        + "".join(": {:<2} ".format(field) for field in row[1:]))
outfile.close()
```

how can i use \n to break the lines up for the text file?

Comment: Where is the nested loop here?

Comment: sorry cold speed meant nested loop ill edit!

Comment: It still isn't clear what you want to do. Why are you mentioning the "shell"?

Comment: that where it giving the error ill take it out as it dont make sence

Comment: Rather than the contents of your `print` statement, you could instead put `":
 {:9} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : ".format(item[0], item[1], item[4], item[2], item[3], item[5])`

Comment: sorry i understand bits of this but not all could you explain more or with an example?

Comment: Can you please just post your expected output to your question? That would help.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, pretty sure he means the python interpreter prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to just check for the `"Couple A"` line and use `ScoreList1` in place of its values when appropriate:

```
ScoreList1= ['04', '05', '01', '07', '08']

nestedList = [["Judge",    "01", "02", "03", "04", "05"],
              ["Couple A", "10", "06", "03", "04", "05"],
              ["Couple B", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05"],
              ["Couple C", "07", "10", "03", "04", "05"],
              ["Couple D", "01", "02", "10", "04", "05"],]

for item in nestedList:
    row = item[:1] + ScoreList1 if item[0] == "Couple A" else item
    print(  ": " + row[0] + " "*(9-len(row[0]))
          + ": " + row[1] + " "*(3-len(row[1]))
          + ": " + row[2] + " "*(3-len(row[2]))
          + ": " + row[3] + " "*(3-len(row[3]))
          + ": " + row[4] + " "*(3-len(row[4]))
          + ": " + row[5] + " "*(3-len(row[5])))
```

Since you indicated you now want the elements of each sublist printed in order, the construction  of the `print()` argument could be simplified:

```
for item in nestedList:
    row = item[:1] + ScoreList1 if item[0] == "Couple A" else item
    print(": {:<8} ".format(row[0])
          + "".join(": {:<2} ".format(field) for field in row[1:]))
```

To extend this to handle two or more substitutions, while you *could* do something like this:

```
ScoreList1= ['04', '05', '01', '07', '08']
ScoreList2= ['07', '02', '01', '02', '08']

for item in nestedList:
    row = (item[:1] + ScoreList1 if item[0] == "Couple A" else
           item[:1] + ScoreList2 if item[0] == "Couple B" else item) # etc, etc
    print(": {:<8} ".format(row[0])
          + "".join(": {:<2} ".format(field) for field in row[1:]))
```

That approach, however, could easily get unwieldy as well as also become relatively slow if there's more than a few to deal with—so it would be better and faster to make the process "table-driven" (using what is known as a [Control Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_table)) and write code handle all the cases once (as opposed writing small fragments of it for each individual case):

```
substitutions = {"Couple A": ScoreList1, "Couple B": ScoreList2}

for item in nestedList:
    row = item[:1] + substitutions.get(item[0], item[1:])
    print(": {:<8} ".format(row[0])
          + "".join(": {:<2} ".format(field) for field in row[1:]))
```

Comment: hi this looks like it would work with a bit of tweaking and help please can you check to see scoreList1 Actually works?

Comment: GraphicsLab: I tested it with `ScoreList1` as shown before I posted it and it appeared to work.

Comment: Where does ScoreList1 Numbers show up ? I need them to show up next to Couple A : ScoreList1 : ScoreList1 etc

Comment: GraphicsLab: This does exactly that (uses the values from `ScoreList1` when printing the output for `Couple A`).

Comment: o yeah just realised is there anyway of keeping it in order?

Comment: GraphicsLab: The argument passed in the `print()` call determines the order. I just copied what you had in your question. Feel free to change it however you want.

Comment: omg I didn't even realise it wasn't keeping the order sorry! would you be able to help with that?

Comment: Just list them in ascending order. i.e. `Item[0]`, `Item[1]`...`Item[5]`. BTW, note that the code modifies the values for the `"Couple A"` sublist in `nestedList`.

Comment: sorry i didn't see this but yes yours works but can you help me add more scorelist next to each couple name as you have but on row 3 etc there gonna be a score list for all of them ps. ive edited mine to show this!

Comment: Just do something similar to the `row` variable's value, only check `if item[0] == "Couple B"` and build the replacement using `ScoreList2`'s values.

Comment: can you do one more as an example please and ill build the rest maybe # telling me what to do im so sorry and your so helpful!

Comment: If you're going to be doing more than a few (as it sounds like could be the case), there may be better ways to handle multiple replacements than explicitly checking for each one. Why do you want to do this in the first place? Because it sounds like it might really be an [_**XY Problem**_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: i need a table in python to show my score and this is the best solution i have found would you be able to help ?

Comment: Didn't see you edited but just did and made what i wanted thank so so much do you want me to post my final code so you can see?!

Comment: when it writes to a text doc it dont keep format can you help? becuase there no \n to make a new line

Comment: I'm skeptical that just writing (more) code for you (that you apparently don't understand) is doing you a favor. As far as updating your question, do whatever you wish, it's yours. To get the missing newline when writing to a file with the `write()` method, you must explicitly add it to the string yourself (by adding a `+ '\n'`)—which `print()` was doing automatically.

Comment: cheers yes i understand why you dont want to give me code thanks for your help just working out what put to put \n thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
ScoreList1 = ['04', '05', '01', '07', '08']



nestedList = [["Judge", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             ["Couple A", 10, 6, 3, 4, 5],
              ["Couple B", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              ["Couple C", 7, 10, 3, 4, 5],
              ["Couple D", 1, 2, 10, 4, 5],]

for item, score in zip(nestedList, ScoreList1):
    print(": {:9} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {}".format(item[0], 
                                                                            item[1], 
                                                                            item[4], 
                                                                            item[2], 
                                                                            item[3], 
                                                                            item[5], 
                                                                            score))
```

Comment: maybe something like `print(": {0[0]} : {0[1]} : {0[4]} : {0[2]} : {0[3]} : {0[5]} : {1}".format(item, score))` for the print?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That, specifically, looses the padding that OP seems to want (could be addressed, though).  Shame OP needs the items out of order.  Otherwise, you could just unroll `item` as arguments to the format function.

Comment: hi  I can see that this is working but I need the score list to be going next to couple A not all of them?